# Step with CopyArtifact in Jenkins pipline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to put step with CopyArtfact to for loop in Jenkins groovy pipeline. Something like this:

```
for (n in branches_numbers)
{
    def buildNum = n.value.toString()
    print '------------------------' + n.value + 'n' + ' ' + buildNum
    step([$class: 'CopyArtifact', filter: 'Tests_Outputs/*.log', fingerprintArtifacts: true, flatten: true, projectName: 'ola_temp', selector: [$class: 'SpecificBuildSelector', buildNumber: '222']])
}
```

1. The step is not running. Only print of first iteration is working, then the script is ending the loop. When I put the step outside the loop, it's working.
2. I have also problem with putting a variable into a buildNumber string. I would like to make something like this:

   ```
   def buildNum = n.value.toString()
   step([$class: 'CopyArtifact', filter: 'Tests_Outputs/*.log', fingerprintArtifacts: true, flatten: true, projectName: 'ola_temp', selector: [$class: 'SpecificBuildSelector', buildNumber: buildNum]])
   ```

The context of this problem is, that I have a job in jenkins, which is running many builds (sometimes 10, but sometimes more). I want to copy artifacts from all builds to one place.

Answer (score 0):

I already know how to iterate in for loop with steps. My 'branches_numbers' is a map, so the solution is to iterate through values:

```
for (n in branches_numbers.values)
{
    buildNum = n.toString()
    step([$class: 'CopyArtifact', filter: 'Tests_Outputs/*.log', fingerprintArtifacts: true, flatten: true, projectName: childJobName, selector: [$class: 'SpecificBuildSelector', buildNumber: buildNum], target: '.'])
```

or put the values to some list and then iterate through it. It also working with variable 'buildNum'. 
Both problems are solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through list of Map values.

```
for (n in branches_numbers.values()) {
buildNum = n.toString()
step([$class: 'CopyArtifact',
    filter: 'Tests_Outputs/*.log', 
    fingerprintArtifacts: true, 
    flatten: true, 
    projectName: childJobName, 
    selector: [$class: 'SpecificBuildSelector', 
       buildNumber: buildNum], 
    target: '.']);
}
```